# ModelState.IsValid always evaluating as true when working with FluentValidation

Tags: c#, fluentvalidation

I am a junior programmer trying to write a simple little bit of code to test out FluentValidation, but without manually calling the validator and adding the results to the modelstate with .AddToModelState, I cannot get the ModelState.IsValid to recognize there are errors in the validation. Am I missing integration somewhere?

This is my Value Model, just a string array with two preset values.

```
using FluentValidation.Attributes;
using Playground2.Validators;

namespace Playground2.Models
{
    [Validator(typeof(ValueValidator))]
    public class Value
    {
        public string[] values = { "value1", "" };
    }

}
```

This is my Validator, looking for two values between 5 and 10 characters.

```
using FluentValidation;
using Playground2.Models;

namespace Playground2.Validators
{
    public class ValueValidator : AbstractValidator<Value>
    {
        public ValueValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.values[0]).Length(5, 10);
            RuleFor(x => x.values[1]).Length(5, 10);
        }
    }
}
```

In the ValuesController, I am simply creating a value object and running a check to see if it passes validation before being output.

```
using FluentValidation.AspNetCore;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Playground2.Models;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Playground2.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<string> Get()
        {
            var value = new Value();

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return new string[] { "Not valid" };      
            }
            else
            {
                return value.values;
            }         
    }
```

But when run, the ModelState.IsValid is always evaluating as true, though the information fed into values is by default invalid.

Comment: I think it would only look at the (request)parameters, via modelbinding. Since there are none (`Get()`), the request is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

FluentValidation follows MVC's/HTML's convention in regard to `GET`s and `POST`s. In this case it's not expecting any validation to be done an a page's initial `GET` as a user wouldn't necessarily have performed any action. They're instead requesting the page to *start* doing something - they haven't gotten around to supplying data.

Once the user fills out information the convention is to submit the data in a HTML `<form>` using a `<button>` or `<input type="submit"/>` to submit the data to the controller via  a `HttpPost` marked method. At this point validation has triggered and you'll be able to correctly interrogate the `ModelState.IsValid`.

Comment: Thank you very much! So I just didn't have it in the right place for testing, gonna have to work on setting up a Post test.